# How can I exit a Scanner Class to perform the rest of the loop?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, rfid

I am accessing a Scanner that helps retrieve RFID Tags from an RFID Reader. I tried using a loop around my `Scanner.next();` but that wouldn't do anything. I think that once my Scanner accesses the RFID Reader's method, that it just permanently stays in there. Is there any way to exit the method for the RFID and then perform the rest of my loop?

```
//The beginning of the loop
while (!doneYet) { 
        //Just a set boolean variable that I try to use later
        Inter = false;
      //A question class that I created, obtains and displays a random question
        Test = Work.randomQuestion();
        Test.display();

      //This is where my problems seem to start, this is the RFID Readers Method.
        rfid.addTagGainListener(new TagGainListener() {
            public void tagGained(TagGainEvent oe) {
                Temp = oe.getValue();
                if (Test.getRFIDTag().equals(Temp)) {
                    System.out.println("You are Correct");
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(count);
                    Inter = true;
                    System.out.println("out");
                    /*
                     * try { System.in.close(); } catch (IOException e) {
                     * TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace();
                     * }
                     */
                } else if (!Test.getRFIDTag().equals(Temp)) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, you are wrong");
                }
                return;
            }
        });

        // Before the RFID Opens though, this code is initiated
        rfid.openAny();
        rfid.waitForAttachment(1000);
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

         //This is where I attempted to control the RFID Reader, but this doesn't work
        if(!Inter){
            sc.next();
        }

         //How I attempt to end the initial while loop
        if(count>10){
            doneYet = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for all of the help.

Comment: I'm really surprised that this code compiles.  Your `count` should be forced to be `final` in which case the `++` should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your scanner doesn't actually do anything. `sc.next()` just skips initial whitespace, and returns the first string of non-whitespace characters; but it just discards that string, never (for example) passing it to `rfid`. As far as I can see, nothing ever triggers `rfid`'s `TagGainListener`. (And why do you add a new `TagGainListener` for each pass through the loop, anyway? Surely you only need one listener?)